# Run VBA code automatically, Moving Cell info from worksheet to worksheet, when cell data changes using a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to move row information from one worksheet table to another when the information in a particular cell changes (I).
The information in the cell (I) changes from 'Current' to 'Expired' if a date in another cell (G) is more than 24 months in the past.
I would like the row of information to move to another worksheet table automatically when the cell (I) changes to 'Expired'.

I have code that works (See Below) when I type in 'Expired' manually, or if I click anywhere within the formula.

**Module 1:**
Sub MoveBasedOnValue()

```
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long
A = Worksheets("Current").UsedRange.Rows.Count
B = Worksheets("Expired").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If B = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Expired").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Current").Range("I1:I" & A)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For C = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Expired" Then
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Expired").Range("A" & B + 1)
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Delete
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Expired" Then
            C = C - 1
        End If
        B = B + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

End Sub

**Sheet 1:**
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Z As Long
Dim xVal As String
On Error Resume Next
If Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = True
For Z = 1 To Target.Count
If Target(Z).Value > 0 Then
Call MoveBasedOnValue
End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKqE2.jpg)

Comment: You need the `Worksheet_Calculate` event handler. The `Worksheet.Change` event does not fire when formulas recalculate.